# Eclipse upgrade to Oxygen results in incorrect error message when defining class

Tags: php, eclipse, compiler-errors

This one is a bit baffling!

After an Eclipse upgrade from Mars to Oxygen on Ubuntu 16.04, all class instantiations appear as syntax errors in the code but execute without any problem.

Sample (executable) code is provided below with an image of way Eclipse renders the error in the source code. The error message reported is 'test_class cannot be resolved to a type' on the line '$test_class = new test_class();'

Code:

```
class test_class
{

    function __construct()
    {
        echo "this is step 2b";
    }

    function test_class()
    {
        echo "this is step 3b";

    }
}

echo "this is step 1";

$test_class = new test_class();

$test_class->test_class();

echo "this is step4";

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <br>this is the last step

</body>
</html>
```

Image:

Any thoughts/help appreciated!

Comment: sorry - unable to add image showing error to post

Comment: You can put them in another file or give them the default namespace `$test_class = new \test_class();`  note the "\", It's a eclipse issue though.  Just like neon cant resolve method hints in a closure.  No doubt there are some other percularities.....

Comment: The class was originally in a separate file. I moved the class into the code body for demo purposes. It makes no difference - it still shows as an error. and btw adding a \ also makes no difference

Comment: well it works in my copy of Oxygen, and in fact if you hover over the error it will say something about global namespace, but whatever... good luck.

Comment: Have just downgraded Eclipse back to Nero and the issue has disappeared. Looks like some sort of bug in Ubuntu Eclipse Oxygen

Answer (score 0):

This is known PDT [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518639). It's doesn't work well when you define and use class in same file.